# Why to added +1 in solution

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming, insertion-sort

Am going trough the some algorithm posts. On reviewing I have a doubt why we added 1 in below code while returning final solution.

```
import sys 

# Recursive function to find minimum  
# number of insertions 
def findMinInsertions(str, l, h): 

    # Base Cases 
    if (l > h): 
        return sys.maxsize 
    if (l == h): 
        return 0
    if (l == h - 1): 
        return 0 if(str[l] == str[h]) else 1

    # Check if the first and last characters are 
    # same. On the basis of the comparison result,  
    # decide which subrpoblem(s) to call 

    if(str[l] == str[h]): 
        return findMinInsertions(str, l + 1, h - 1) 
    else: 

        **return (min(findMinInsertions(str, l, h - 1), 
                findMinInsertions(str, l + 1, h)) + 1)** 

# Driver Code 
if __name__ == "__main__": 

    str = "abc"
    print(findMinInsertions(str, 0, len(str) - 1))
```

Comment: The `l` and `h` arguments seems to be indexes into the string `str`. You need to add `1` to get to the *next* character.

Comment: I have edited the post please check again @Someprogrammerdude . Why we added 1 in the end of the return statement return (min(findMinInsertions(str, l, h - 1),findMinInsertions(str, l + 1, h)) + 1)

Comment: What is this program doing, seems to me like 1 is added because current execution of recursion should be counted as 1. Like if str[l] != str[h], an operation need to be done which is counted as 1, before reducing the current problem to sub-problems.

Comment: This algo is using to find the minimum number of insertions in string to make it palindrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
findMinInsertions(str, l, h - 1)
```

is the minimum number of insertions after the last character is inserted.

```
findMinInsertions(str, l + 1, h)
```

is the minimum number of insertions after the first character is inserted.

```
min(findMinInsertions(str, l, h - 1), findMinInsertions(str, l + 1, h)) # (a)
```

is the minimum number of insertions after the first character or last character is inserted. To get the minimum number of insertions you can take the minimum number of insertions after one character was inserted **(a)** and add one insertion (since one character already was inserted).

Answer (score 0):

+1 used to count. we  need to add  while returning back to parent node ( start from 0 { return 0 }+ 1 ).
and then taking min of two recursive call.

Comment: While returning the minimum values from the recursion it counting the minimum tuple count that we have. Then why there is need to add 1 in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm doesn't find minimum number of insertion during insertion sort but merely gives an upper bound on the number of insertions. It's easy to check this by simply running the algorithm on the string "abc" and see the result is 2, while the real minimum insertions is 0.

Let's have a look over the recursive step:

```
if(str[l] == str[h]): 
    return findMinInsertions(str, l + 1, h - 1) 
else: 

    return (min(findMinInsertions(str, l, h - 1), 
            findMinInsertions(str, l + 1, h)) + 1)
```

if str[l] == str[h], the minimum amount of insertions is given by the values of the characters between them because str[l] and str[h] can stay in their relative position (meaning str[h] will stay to the right of str[l]), hence we will move / insert only the characters between the indices l and h.

Once you realize what happens in the equal case, you can understand that in the case of inequality there is a **chance** of moving one of the characters str[l] or str[h].

**Notice** that since it's only a chance of moving a character, the algorithm yields upper bound on number of insertions and not the minimum.

Comment: This algorithm is not for insertion sort. Actually this algorithm count how many minimum insertions we needed to make string palindrome.

Comment: @ParulGarg you should mention the purpose of the algorithm in your question.